# Multiple If statements in C# do not work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

I've encountered really strange issue with if statement. I got image in canvas, which i want to move/drag with mouse/touch. Movement of image works fine. I want to add boundaries, so image would never leave viewport.. image is scaled (its height) to height of canvas, so I just need to add left and right border:

```
if (planTranslate.X < 0)
{
   planTranslate.X = 0;
}
else planTranslate.X = startPosition.X - vector.X;

if (planTranslate.X > maxX)
{
   planTranslate.X = maxX;
}
else planTranslate.X = startPosition.X - vector.X;
```

First condition works as expected, but second does not and I have no idea why.

When I put `if planTranslate.X > maxX` before `if planTranslate.X < 0` image stops on right side of viewport but keep going on left.

Comment: Suggestion: use debugger and check your variables values at runtime.

Comment: you're overwriting your if statements with your elses

Comment: How I would do it: first calculate the new planTranslate.X; then make sure the new value is between 0 and maxX.

Comment: i have put planTranslate.X value to textblock.Text property so I know its value at runtime..

Comment: You still need step-by-step debugger to see how value changes and find a bug.

Comment: @HansKesting thx for suggestioni will try it

Comment: @HansKesting thx buddy! i ve declared local variable newX (newly calculatted X position), compared to 0 and maxX and if condition is  true, newX is assigned  to planTranslate.X else planTranslate gets 0 or maxX and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you simply need to compute the difference and then check the max/min values

```
planTranslate.X = startPosition.X - vector.X;

if (planTranslate.X < 0)
{
   planTranslate.X = 0;
}

if (planTranslate.X > maxX)
{
   planTranslate.X = maxX;
}
```